# Trouble with classes in ruby and codewars

Tags: ruby

so i am trying a kata on Codewars: Flexible Card Game

http://www.codewars.com/kata/5436fdf34e3d6cb156000350/train/ruby

the code I have written has passed most tests but trips up at the end giving this:

```
#draw
chooses cards from the end
Test Passed: Value == [[:clubs, 13]]

removes cards from the deck
Test Passed: Value == 51

returns the cards that were drawn
Test Passed: Value == 1

Expected [:clubs, 13] to be a Card
chooses cards from the end

Test Passed: Value == [[:clubs, 12], [:clubs, 13]]
removes cards from the deck

Test Passed: Value == 50
returns the cards that were drawn

Test Passed: Value == 2
Expected [:clubs, 12] to be a Card
Expected [:clubs, 13] to be a Card
```

What I don't understand is that when the test calls the method draw it seems to expect to different returns from the same method. I'm sure it's something I've done wrong but I cant see it. Any help would be great. Here is my code:

```
class Card 
 include Comparable
 attr_accessor :suit, :rank
  def initialize(suit, rank)

      @suit = suit
      @rank = rank

  end

  def <=> (another_card)
    if self.rank < another_card.rank
         -1
    elsif self.rank > another_card.rank
          1
    else
          0
    end
  end

  def face_card?
    @rank > 10 ? true : false
  end

  def to_s
    @rank_hash = {13 => "King", 12 => "Queen", 11 => "Jack", 10 => "10", 9 => "9", 8 => "8", 7 => "7", 6 => "6", 5 => "5", 4 => "4", 3 => "3", 2 => "2", 1 => "Ace"}
    @suit_hash = {:clubs => "Clubs", :spades => "Spades", :hearts => "Hearts", :diamonds => "Diamonds"}
    "#{@rank_hash[@rank]} of #{@suit_hash[@suit]}"
  end

end

class Deck < Card
attr_accessor :cards
  def initialize

    @rank_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
    @suit_array = [:hearts, :diamonds, :spades, :clubs]
    @cards = @suit_array.product(@rank_array)

  end

  def count
    @cards.size
  end

  def shuffle
    @cards.shuffle!
  end

  def draw(n=1)
  @cards.pop(n)
  end

end
```

Comment: `What I don't understand is that when the test calls the method draw it seems to expect to different returns from the same method.` Can you explain more?

Comment: first it calls draw and  gets : chooses cards from the end
Test Passed: Value == [[:clubs, 13]] but after it calls it again and wants a different response so says this: Expected [:clubs, 13] to be a Card
chooses cards from the end  I understand now it needs an iff statement but i dont know how to construct it

Comment: It's brutally inefficient to duplicate data like `@rank_hash` and `@suit_hash` inside a method like `to_s` and still bad form to declare `@suit_array` for each and every instance of this object. What you should do is split those out as constants like `RANK_HASH` as they're not going to change and having multiple copies of those is pointless.

Comment: Im currently being taught to refactor after i get a solution. Criticising code seems a little pointless if your just criticising form and not pointing out errors. I can fix the form when it works. "Your form" doesnt make much sense to me because im not as advanced as you. Thanks for helping tho.

Comment: If you've solved it yourself, make it an answer or delete the question.. don't leave a solved question hanging without an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the initialize method. Below fixed the issue.

```
def initialize
@cards = []
@rank_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
@suit_array = [:hearts, :diamonds, :spades, :clubs]
  @suit_array.each do |suit|
    @rank_array.each do |rank|
      each_card = Card.new(suit, rank)
      @cards << each_card
    end
  end
end
```